# Is there a good library in Node for asynchronous communication between the client and server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rpc, websocket

Instead of creating every websocket and defining the entire structure by hand, is there a library that will let me run a function on the Node.js server, that can call a related function on all clients connected to the server simultaneously? Likewise, can I securely call a server function FROM the client browser? I feel like every time I have to construct a command to send over the web socket, I'm working on the transmission layer instead of the application layer, and I *want* to be thinking at the higher layer the entire time.

I wouldn't mind building something like this myself if it doesn't already exist, but I have a hard time believing this isn't solved on node already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really looking for is an node.js RPC solution. Here are a couple of node.js RPC options:

- [DNode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) - shows some good examples.
- [BERT-RPC](https://github.com/rtomayko/node-bertrpc)
- [nowjs](http://nowjs.com/)

I have not personally used them, but they look like they have good potential.

Comment: Excellent comparison of DNode and NowJS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317282/what-is-the-difference-between-dnode-and-nowjs

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [now.js](http://nowjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [msg-rpc](https://github.com/rooseve/msg-rpc), it just provides the rpc support you need, also no particular requirement for the websocket library of server/client you already have. Tell how to send out a message and forward the messages received, that's all.