# Are there any websocket plugins for nodejs

Tags: sockets, node.js, websocket

Are there any websocket plugins for nodejs; I would like to develop some application that uses websockets.

Answer (score 7):

**Checkout [Socket.IO](http://socket.io)** - it's a widely used and powerful Node module for socket connections.

Comment: For sure socket.io is the best solution, because it will also work on browsers which do not support websockets like for example Internet Explorer.

Comment: Also, don't fail to mention [Zappa](http://thechangelog.com/post/1582034775/zappa-razor-sharp-dsl-for-modern-web-apps), a full-stack web-based appserver with socket.io already installed as part of its toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

[WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node) is a pure WebSocket implementation in node.js that supports the latest version of the WebSocket spec (version 8), and is still being actively maintained.

Otherwise [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) has broader browser support because it can fall back to things such as Flash Sockets, long lived iframes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Like cmpolis mentioned, Socket.IO is excellent.  Just upgraded to 0.8 too.

[nowjs](http://nowjs.com/) also provides a higher-level api if you like more abstraction.

Similar to nowjs, [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) allows you to call remote functions between the client and server and vice versa.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317282/what-is-the-difference-between-dnode-and-nowjs) is a great SO answer delineating the differences between them.