# Decouple GWT Asynchronous callbacks

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, coding-style, state-pattern

I have the following problem:
I am trying to model a process using GWT, where i have a couple of views with a couple of submit buttons. And pressing button1 will create a server interaction and if everything was ok, the next view will be loaded. My problem is now that I get really nasty spaghetti code (just very highlevel to show you what i mean):

```
onClick {
    AsyncCallback {
       onSuccess {

           load new view with another clickhandler and an asynccallback

       }
    }
}
```

Is there some way to create some kind of abstraction or something? Maybe a state pattern? How? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a very good question - and probably one without a definitive answer. It's a problem that applies to many frameworks, not just GWT, so I like your idea to look at this with some simplified code. I'll make this a little bit longer, to show what even just 4 very simple callbacks look like:

#### Nested callbacks

```java
alice.call("a", new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
    bob.call("b", new Callback() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {
        charlie.call("c", new Callback() {

          @Override
          public void onSuccess() {
            daisy.call("d", new Callback() {

              @Override
              public void onSuccess() {
                // finished
              }

            });
          }

        });
      }

    });
  }

});
```

#### Named callbacks

You can use your IDE to refactor this easily into named callbacks (hint: Please read the callbacks from bottom to top!):

```java
final Callback daisyCallback = new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
    // finished
  }
};

final Callback charlieCallback = new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
    daisy.call("d", daisyCallback);
  }
};

final Callback bobCallback = new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
    charlie.call("c", charlieCallback);
  }
};

final Callback aliceCallback = new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
    bob.call("b", bobCallback);
  }
};

alice.call("a", aliceCallback);
```

- Problem: The control flow is not so immediately obvious anymore.
- Still, an IDE can help by using "Search References" (Ctrl-G in Eclipse) or something similar.

#### Event Bus (or Observer/Publish-Subscribe pattern)

This is how the same calls look like with an event bus:

```java
alice.call("a", new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
    bus.fireEvent(BusEvent.ALICE_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT);
  }
});

bus.addEventListener(BusEvent.ALICE_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT, new BusEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onEvent(final BusEvent busEvent) {
    bob.call("b", new Callback() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {
        bus.fireEvent(BusEvent.BOB_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT);
      }
    });

  }
});

bus.addEventListener(BusEvent.BOB_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT, new BusEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onEvent(final BusEvent busEvent) {
    charlie.call("c", new Callback() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {
        bus.fireEvent(BusEvent.CHARLIE_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT);
      }
    });

  }
});

bus.addEventListener(BusEvent.CHARLIE_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT, new BusEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onEvent(final BusEvent busEvent) {
    daisy.call("d", new Callback() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {
        bus.fireEvent(BusEvent.DAISY_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT);
      }
    });

  }
});

bus.addEventListener(BusEvent.DAISY_SUCCESSFUL_EVENT, new BusEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onEvent(final BusEvent busEvent) {
    // finished
  }
});
```

- Under the right circumstances (when it's very clear what each event means, and
  if you don't have too many), this pattern can make things very nice and clear.
- But in other cases, it can make the control flow more confusing (and you easily get twice the lines of code).
- It's harder to use your IDE to find out about the control flow.
- The GWT History mechanism is a very positive example for where to use this technique reasonably.

#### Divide and Conquer

In my experience, it's often a good idea to "divide and conquer" by mixing nesting and named callbacks:

```java
final Callback charlieCallback = new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {

    daisy.call("d", new Callback() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {
        // finished
      }
    });
  }
};

alice.call("a", new Callback() {

  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {

    bob.call("b", new Callback() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {

        charlie.call("c", charlieCallback);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Depending on the situation, two nested callbacks are often still readable, and they reduce jumping around between methods when reading the code by 50%.

<sub>(I created a pastebin of my examples here, if you like to play around with them: http://pastebin.com/yNc9Cqtb)</sub>

Comment: BusEventHandler will look more compatible with GWT style than BusEventListener

Comment: I think I should add a note of caution: The examples are not actual GWT code!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I now went for the MVP/Bus architecture, works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Spaghetti code is a tricky problem in GWT as it is in Javascript, where much of your code is structured around asynchronous callbacks.

Some of the techniques to deal with it that are described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265743/node-js-what-techniques-are-there-for-writing-clean-simple-callback-code) could apply.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested approach to avoid coupling between widgets is to use EventBus. Read more details here https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture#events

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use MVP from very beginning. Use Activities and Places. Your code will be clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
changeview(boolean first){
        if(first)
        {
                firstView.setVisible(true);
                secondView.setVisible(false);
        }else{
                firstView.setVisible(false);
                secondView.setVisible(true);
        }
}

onClick {
    AsyncCallback {
       onSuccess {
                changeView(false);
       }
    }
}
```

Switch between views by above.