# How to chain async methods of chrome.* API without callback spaghetti code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting out with building a Chrome extension and it looks like most of the functions there are asynchronous that use a callback function, even the ones where one would expect synchronous behavior, like `chrome.tabs.getCurrent`.

So, say I want to have a popup for a browserAction, and when the user clicks on a button to transfer some object as a message to background.js. That object should contain, for the purposes of this example, the current's tab URL and a cookie value. Both `chrome.tabs.getCurrent(cb)` and `chrome.cookies.get(details, cb)` require a callback. How do I collect the data to pass *without* doing something like the following:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(
   function(currentTab){
      var url = currentTab.url;
      chrome.cookies.get({...}, 
         function(cookie){
             var msg = { "url" : url, "value" : cookie.value };
             chrome.runtime.connect().postMessage(msg);
         });
   }
);
```

Comment: [I recommend looking into promise objects](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/).

Comment: One way to avoid nested callbacks is through [Promises](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/), but if the API doesn't provide that, you may have to roll your own implementation.

Comment: @zzzzBov, so would that work for chrome extension development. Doesn't look like they support promise objects

Comment: @NewDev, you'd have to use a promise object implementation. It's not a native browser feature.

Comment: @Bergi, I guess the question could be restated as "are promises possible/available for chrome extension development?"

Comment: …and if you don't want promises, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265743/node-js-what-techniques-are-there-for-writing-clean-simple-callback-code) as well.

Comment: @NewDev: Yes, just import a library like Q and use it. Btw, I'm not sure whether they would be of much help for the posted example code, as nesting seems unavoidable there (you're accessing both `url` and `cookie` from the innermost callback)

Comment: @Bergi, yes, that's because I need to collect the data before posting. Thanks everyone, I think I have enough to go by.