# Q.denodeify example not executing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I am a newbie in node just trying out an example on the usage of Q. I am not able to get the log `'addition completed'` printed. I am getting `'inside 7'` & `'7'` in the output. What am I doing wrong?

My code is

```
var Q = require('q');

function Add(callback){

    setTimeout(function(){
        var a, b, c;
        b = 3; 
        a = 4;
        c = a + b; 
        console.log("inside "+c);
        callback(c);
    }, 2000); 

}

var promise = Q.denodeify(Add);

function callback(x){
    console.log(x);
}

promise(callback).then(function(){
    console.log('addition completed');
});
```

Comment: Your denodeify not working

Comment: ok. i just posted code that works but i need an explanation for it.

Comment: you don't need q for the promise, check my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i was trying out a tutorial example online given for Q using code similar to one i posted and wanted to learn how to do so. i understand q is not required for this example.

Answer (score 1):

This sample code won't answer any questions you might have about [`the q library`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q).
Instead, it just demonstrates **how you can use a promise instead of a callback to complete an asynchronous task** -- which seems like the underlying goal of your code.

(For more info and examples, you can check out [MDN: Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise))

Note that promises are an **alternative** to callbacks, so an expression like `promise(callback)` is not something you'd typically write.

Also, I only looked at `q` very briefly, but I think **`Q.denodeify` might not be the correct method** to use for the task you're trying to accomplish.

**For suggestions specific to `q`, you might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265743/node-js-what-techniques-are-there-for-writing-clean-simple-callback-code#19579011) helpful.**

```js
function add(){

  // Calling `add` will return a promise that eventually resolves to `7`
  // There is no way this particular promise can reject (unlike most promises)
  const myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // The anonymous function we pass to `setTimeout` runs asynchronously
    // Whevever it is done, it applies the promise's `resolve` function to `c`
    setTimeout(function(){
      const
        a = 4,
        b = 3,
        c = a + b;
      resolve(c);
    }, 200);
  });
  return myPromise;
}

// `add` returns a promise that always resolves to `7`
// The `.then` method of this promise lets us specify a function that 
//   does something with the resolved value when it becomes available
add().then(function(resolvedValue){
  console.log("addition result: " + resolvedValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked it a bit and got it to work. But i am not able to understand clearly why this worked and the one prior to this failed. Hope someone call help with an explanation.

My new code is

```
var Q = require('q');

function Add(callback){

    setTimeout(function(){
        var a, b, c;
        b = 3; 
        a = 4;
        c = a + b; 
        console.log("inside "+ c);
        callback();

    }, 2000); 

}

var promise = Q.denodeify(Add);

promise().then(function(){
    console.log('addition completed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example for the promise

```
 var Q = require('q');

    function add(callback){

        return new Promise(function ( resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                var a, b, c;
                b = 3;
                a = 4;
                c = a + b;
                console.log("inside "+c);
                callback(c);
                if(c){
                    resolve(c);
                }else{
                    reject();
                }
            }, 2000);

        });
    }

    //var promise = Q.nbind(add);

    function callback(x){
        console.log(x);
    }

    add(callback).then(function(){
        console.log('addition completed');
    }).catch(function (E) {
        console.log(E);
    });
```